# Integral of the derivative of a function with respect to another multivariate function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $g(x,y)$ be a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h(x,y)=(g(x,y)^2-1)^n$.

I want to compute $\frac{d^nh}{dg^n}$. My initial idea was that we can write

$h=(g^2-1)^n$

$\frac{dh}{dg}=n(g^2-1)^{n-1}\frac{d(g^2-1)}{dg}=n(g^2-1)^{n-1}(2g)$

and so forth for each derivative.

Is this correct? I feel like I'm missing some sort of derivative of $g$.

The next part is that I need to compute $\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{d^nh(x,y)}{dg(x,y)^n}\sin(x)dxdy$ with $[y_1,y_2]\subseteq[0,2\pi]$ and $[x_1,x_2]\subseteq[0,\pi]$. If I can get an explicit form of the $n$th derivative I can probably calculate this. Otherwise, is there a rule for integrating a derivative multiplied by another function?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what it means to differentiate with respect to a function. I would assume, like you, that it means to differentiate the single-variable function $h(u) = (u^2 -1)^n$, and then substitute $u = g(x,y)$. What exactly is the domain of the double integral?

Comment: @AlexProvost The integrals range over $y_1$, $y_2$ and $x_1$, $x_2$ respectively where $y_i\in[0,2\pi]$ and $x_i\in[0,\pi]$. I hope this helps

Comment: Why are you mentioning four variables? I thought we were in $\mathbb R^2$. In any case, I think you should edit your post to add those important details.

Comment: @AlexProvost, I have updated the post. Hopefully this makes the double integral domain more clear.